# Override Newsletter Subscriber Controller - not working

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers, newsletter

I realise, there are several Questions that are basically the same - with solutions. Sadly, I still can't figure out what is wrong.

**Problem:**
I'd like to **extend** the `Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController`to add some **custom code**.
The new Controller, which extends said controller, is never called.

We use Magento 1.9.2.1 with some manual security patches.

Here is what I've done, so far:

**Registered a new Module** in `app/etc/modules/MM_Newsletter.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <MM_Newsletter>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </MM_Newsletter>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

**Set how it should override the controller** in `app/code/local/MM/Newsletter/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MM_Newsletter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MM_Newsletter>
    </modules>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletter>
                <!--<subscriber>-->
                    <!--<new>-->
                        <args>
                            <modules>
                                <MM_Newsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">MM_Newsletter</MM_Newsletter>
                            </modules>
                        </args>
                    <!--</new>-->
                <!--</subscriber>-->
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

With the commented nodes I tried to reflect the actual route that is called from the frontend. Either way, it doesn't work.

**Extended the Controller in** `app/code/local/MM/Newsletter/controllers/MM_Newsletter_SubscriberController.php`

```
<?php

require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Newsletter').DS.'SubscriberController.php';

class MM_Newsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController{

    public function newAction()
    {
       // some custom code ...

        parent::newAction();
    }
}
```

The custom code is never executed.
The caches are always emptied, when I push changes to the server. They are guaranteed to be empty, even though I checked manually, too.
XDebug is set up and breakpoints in the custom controller are never hit.
When i let it `die()`, to see if just the debugger doesn't register correctly, it also just calls the original controller and does not perform the custom code.

**Is there something missing?**
FYI: I also tried the older rewrite syntax in the xml config, which didn't work either.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your controller location should be

```
app/code/local/MM/Newsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php
```

Content:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Newsletter').DS.'SubscriberController.php';

class MM_Newsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController
{
    public function newAction()
    {
        // some custom code ...
        parent::newAction();
    }
}
```

Also clean your **app/code/local/MM/Newsletter/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MM_Newsletter>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </MM_Newsletter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletter>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <MM_Newsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">MM_Newsletter</MM_Newsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Clear cache.

Comment: Many thanks, It had to be something basic.
The comments in the config was just to illustrate another attempt and have been removed, since. 
Thank you, again!